# How do you define/organize proto files for a project with multiple python packages?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, package, grpc

How do I define and organize gRPC proto files for a project with two (or more) python packages?

Suppose I have the following monorepo structure:

```
my_project/  
 |
 |-my_client_pkg/
 |  |_Dockerfile
 |  |_setup.py
 |  |_my_client/
 |     |___init__.py
 |     |_client.py
 |
  -my_server_pkg/
    |_Dockerfile
    |_setup.py
    |_my_server/
       |___init__.py
       |_server.py
```

I want to use gRPC to connect these two services together. I can add a `protos/` directory, with the appropriate child directories like so:

```
my_project/  
 |
 |-protos/
 |  |_my_client_pkg/
 |  |  |_my_client.proto
 |  |
 |  |_my_server_pkg/
 |     |_my_server.proto
 |
 |-my_client_pkg/
 |  |_Dockerfile
 |  |_setup.py
 |  |_my_client/
 |     |___init__.py
 |     |_client.py
 |
  -my_server_pkg/
    |_Dockerfile
    |_setup.py
    |_my_server/
       |___init__.py
       |_server.py
```

and this works: I can generate the .py files correctly, with the correct import statements. The problem with this approach is that I must duplicate everything from `my_client.proto` into `my_server.proto`. If I need to make a change, it must be in both files, something is obviously error prone. It really seems to defeat the purpose of protobufs.

How should I be organizing my proto files? Is it possible to define the proto in one place, and then use the proto `import` statement to seamlessly duplicate the definitions? Should I be doing something completely different?

Edit:
Here is an example proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message AbcRequest {
  string utterance = 1;
}

message AbcResponse {
  string value = 2;
}

service Abc {
  rpc most_similar(AbcRequest) returns (AbcResponse) {}
}
```

I did try defining the proto in a single place, and then importing it:

```
my_project/  
 |
 |-protos/
 |  |-base.proto
 |  |_my_client_pkg/
 |  |  |_my_client.proto
 |  |
 |  |_my_server_pkg/
 |     |_my_server.proto
```

Where my_client.proto and my_server.proto both just have:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "protos/base.proto";
```

However, when I generated the python code, the *_grpc.py file had nothing in it. Should I be doing something else for the importing to work like this?

Comment: Protobuf supports an `import` statement. How about you take the part you duplicate and separate it into another .proto file. Then you can import that file from your client and server .proto files. If that doesn't make sense, please share the .proto files - it should be easier to come up with a solution then

Comment: @Michał I updated the question to include an example proto, as well as my prior attempts at importing.

Comment: Your *_grpc.py file will have nothing in it, since there is no service defined in the corresponding .proto file. You should however have access to a *_pb2.py file instead. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, there is *_pb2.py file, but it is mostly empty. The *_pb2.py generated when I simply duplicate the definitions has much more in it.

Comment: what do you mean by mostly empty? Also, where do you put your compiled .proto files (the _pb2.py and _grpc.py files)? How do you run your client? from _server.py and _client.py? Are you on Python3 (Python3 has different import mechanics than Python2)?

Comment: If you're looking for OO style inheritance for .proto files (it sounds as if you are), I found this in the c# tutorial "Don't go looking for facilities similar to class inheritance, though – protocol buffers don't do that." ... Search for "inheritance" in here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial

Answer (score 1):

protobuf `import` statements allow you to access definitions defined in other files, but will only generated code for messages/services defined in that file.
`syntax = "proto3";
import "protos/base.proto";`

Will generate empty files because there are no service/messages defined in this file.

The code for the file you imported will live in `base_pb2_grpc`.

I would recommend having a single `my_service.proto` file with all your definitions, and just referencing the generated `_pb2_grpc.py` file from both your my_client and my_server package.